# Including NaN values in function applied to Pandas GroupBy object

Tags: pandas-groupby

I would like to calculate the mean of replicate measurements and return NaN when one or both replicates have an NaN value. I am aware that `groupby` excludes NaN values, but it took me some time to realize `apply` was doing the same thing. Below is an example of my code. It only returns NaN when both replicates have missing data. In this example I would like it to return NaN for Sample 1, Assay 2. Instead, it is behaving as if I applied `np.nanmean` and returns the one nonzero element, 27.0. Any ideas on a strategy to include NaN values in the function I am applying?

```
    In[4]: import pandas as pd
    In[5]: import numpy as np
    In[6]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Sample ID': ['Sample 1', 'Sample 1', 'Sample 1', 'Sample 1', 'Sample 2', 'Sample 2', 'Sample 2', 'Sample 2'],
                              'Assay': ['Assay 1', 'Assay 1', 'Assay 2', 'Assay 2', 'Assay 1', 'Assay 1', 'Assay 2', 'Assay 2'],
                              'Replicate': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                              'Value': [34.0, 30.0, 27.0, np.nan, 16.0, 18.0, np.nan, np.nan]})
    In[7]: df
    Out[8]: 
      Sample ID    Assay  Replicate  Value
    0  Sample 1  Assay 1          1   34.0
    1  Sample 1  Assay 1          2   30.0
    2  Sample 1  Assay 2          1   27.0
    3  Sample 1  Assay 2          2    NaN
    4  Sample 2  Assay 1          1   16.0
    5  Sample 2  Assay 1          2   18.0
    6  Sample 2  Assay 2          1    NaN
    7  Sample 2  Assay 2          2    NaN

    In[9]: Group = df.groupby(['Sample ID', 'Assay'])
    In[10]: df2 = Group['Value'].aggregate(np.mean).unstack() 
    Out[82]: 
    Assay      Assay 1  Assay 2
    Sample ID                  
    Sample 1      32.0     27.0
    Sample 2      17.0      NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is during the conversion that happens on the `mean` function execution.

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html):

> Array containing numbers whose mean is desired. If a is not an array,
>   a conversion is attempted.

I was able to make it work by manually doing the conversion by defining a function that calls the `mean`

```
def aggregate_func(serie):
    return np.mean(serie.values)
```

and using that function on the `aggregate` call like so:

```
df2 = Group['Value'].aggregate(aggregate_func).unstack()
```

Another option is that the function `np.average` behaves the same as `np.mean` if you don't provide the optional weight parameter. But it looks like the conversion works as expected.

Using it gave me the expected result:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Sample ID': ['Sample 1', 'Sample 1', 'Sample 1', 'Sample 1', 'Sample 2', 'Sample 2', 'Sample 2', 'Sample 2'],
                              'Assay': ['Assay 1', 'Assay 1', 'Assay 2', 'Assay 2', 'Assay 1', 'Assay 1', 'Assay 2', 'Assay 2'],
                              'Replicate': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                              'Value': [34.0, 30.0, 27.0, np.nan, 16.0, 18.0, np.nan, np.nan]})

Group = df.groupby(['Sample ID', 'Assay'])
df2 = Group['Value'].aggregate(np.average).unstack()
```

results in

```
Assay       Assay 1 Assay 2
Sample ID       
Sample 1    32.0    NaN
Sample 2    17.0    NaN
```

Comment: Brilliant! I was really struggling with this one. Thanks so much!